# type erasure for functions in rust

Tags: c++, rust

Consider this C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

std::function<int(int, int)> foo(int c) {
  auto add = [] (int a, int b) { return a + b; };
  auto sub = [] (int a, int b) { return a - b; };
  if (c > 42) {
    return add;
  } else {
    return sub;
  }
}

int main() {
  cout << foo(100)(10, 20) << '\n';
}
```

Both lambdas (`add` and `sub`) are type erased via `std::function` and that function is then called in main.
I am wondering how can I replicate this pattern in rust?

Comment: i am not sure if I understand what you mean with "type erased via `std::function`". `add` and `sub` are generic, but the `std::function` returned from `foo` is only for `int`s. The type that is erased is that of the lambda contained within the `std::function`, is that what you mean?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 let me clarify the question a bit. I have removed auto and made the types explicit. And yes, that is what I meant. each lambda is a distinct type, but when we assign to std::function, we have effectively erased that type. (std::function achieves this via a virtual method in its implementation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A rather exact translation of your example would be the following snippet.

```rust
fn foo(c: i32) -> Box<dyn Fn(i32, i32) -> i32> {
    let add = |a, b| a + b;
    let sub = |a, b| a - b;
    Box::new(if c > 42 { add } else { sub })
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", foo(100)(10, 20));
}
```

A type of closure is unnameable, so we coerce it to a trait object and store it on the heap, which is as far as I understand, is about the same thing `std::function` does.

Comment: > is about the same thing std::function does.

Correct. It implements a virtual interface with call operator, and saves the base class pointer.

Comment: I think `std::function` is allowed to employ a small size optimization where it stores the function within itself instead of heap allocating it. It's sometimes hard to remember which types can't do optimizations like that due to other requirements though.

Comment: @chris in rust you'd probably that "by hand" using a dedicated enum, although sadly that enum wouldn't be a function as [Fn (and friends) still can't be implemented in stable](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29625).

Comment: Notice that since the closures do not actually borrow their context, you can do `fn foo(c: i32) -> &'static dyn Fn(i32, i32) -> i32` as your signature, avoiding a heap allocation. This will still erase the type and dynamically dispatch, although we are bound to static functions.